# Unsuccessful in one position but Recruiter Offered to Forward Resume to A Different Role -- Update Resume?

Tags: resume, job-search, recruitment

I was recently unsuccessful in one search at a company but in all cases, I had positive feedback; they went with a candidate who had deeper knowledge in a specific aspect of the role.

However, the recruiter offered to forward my resume if there were any other current positions in which I was interested but was clear she wouldn't be that recruiter (very specific recruiting verticals).

There is one role that has a different functional focus (digital project manager (original role) vs marketing manager). Both are very relevant to my background but the original resume was very project focused.

Is it a good idea to send a resume that is more relevant to the second position?  Does it look bad to revamp a resume the recruiter has in-hand (and adapt current bullets) to the new position listing?

Answer (score 4):

> Is it a good idea to send a resume that is more relevant to the second position?

**Absolutely**.

As a general guideline, it is recommended to *tailor your resume to better fit the role you are applying to*.

In this case, this means that you should **focus your resume more towards marketing manager**, trying to highlight those aspects that are more favorable for that role.

Comment: Yes, and to add to this - there's no harm in being up-front with recruiters about this. Recruiters know that resumes are tailored to the position (or at least role type) and putting in the effort to customize here is a signal you care about this company. Of course, your resume should always be truthful; someone looking at two versions side by side shouldn't wonder how your title or college major suddenly changed!